# Access log file created by syslog as a normal user

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, users, syslog

I've created a user, but I'm not able to access my log file in /var/log. It says permission denied. I don't want to use sudo, as I want to access it from scripts too. I was able to achieve this by adding the user in /etc/sudoers file and adding NOPASSWD so that it doesn't ask for password. But I'm assuming it'll elevate the privileges of the new user to that of root, which I don't want. I'm not able to change the user of the log file too, probably since syslog is not owned by root, but by syslog user and it doesn't have enough privileges to do that.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @Ravexina thanks for quick reply. I'm not able to check right now. But I remember syslog user is "syslog", group is "adm" and file permissions are -rw------- or -rw-r-----. I'll check as soon as possible. But I want to access another log file /var/log/dm.log, even if I change the permissions I'm having to use sudo and the permissions of all the log files such as /var/log/syslog are changing, even though I had a seperate conf file in syslog.d directory.

Comment: add your user to `adm` group and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Ravexina thank you, will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Ravexina, it says Permission denied even after adding the user to adm group.

Comment: Hi @Ravexina, sorry. When I added user to adm group with usermod instead of adduser, I'm able to access the file without needing the password. Thank you very much.